# Transferring book marks from saved user folder

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, google-chrome, bookmarks, favorites

My staff is getting new machines, running Windows 10, that are replacing their old machines, which ran Windows 7.  I have copied their old user files onto the new machines.  These old files include their saved favorites from their browsers, and these are accessible directly through Windows, but they are not appearing in their browsers.  Their bookmarks are not appearing in their browsers at all, although they do appear in places like (for Chrome) C:\Users{username}\AppData\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks (no file extension).

How do I make the favorites and bookmarks appear in the browsers again?

Comment: Verify they have permissions on the folders in question.  If you transferred them from another machine, then it's very likely they don't have any permissions, since their previous user does not exist on their new machine.  You have provided no information to indicate you are using an AD domain.

Comment: Copy and paste the old bookmarks file ( C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks) to the same place on the new machines, be sure chrome is closed when you paste.